# Netty how to handle exception on HttpChunkAggregator

Tags: java, netty

I have an application where I am using HttpChunkAggregator to avoid dealing with chunks because I need to parse the whole input as a unit to create the `json` node. Since `HttpChunkAggregator` must take a `maxContentLength`, so I need to handle cases when the incoming request exceeds the content size, I want to return a nice formatted error message to the client. Here is what I am doing:

1: Subclass `HttpChunkAggregator` and override the `exceptionCaught` method

```
public class MyHttpChunkAggregator extends HttpChunkAggregator {

public MyHttpChunkAggregator(int maxContentLength) {
    super(maxContentLength);
}   

//@Override

public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext context, ExceptionEvent ee)
        throws Exception {      
if (ee.getCause() instanceof TooLongFrameException) {           

logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception caught in channel handler", ee.getCause());

HttpResponse httpResponse;

try {

 //build a http response

 httpResponse = //call my function here to build a response

    ee.getChannel().write(httpResponse);

    ee.getChannel().close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Throwables.propagate(ioe);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

2: Add my customized handler to the pipeline

```
ChannelPipeline p = Channels.pipeline();

p.addLast("requestDecoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());

p.addLast("responseEncoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());

p.addLast("chunkAggregator", new MyHttpChunkAggregator(1048576)));

//adding the real business handle class to parse the input content
```

By doing this, I am able to achieve `messageRecived` NOT being invoked in my real business handler since if the input is too big, I don't want to proceed anymore. However, I am currently see two issues that I want to address:

1. `exceptionCaught` is invoked multiple times. I want to send a nice formatted message the first time it happens and then permanently terminate the processing of this request.
2. because it is invoked multiple times, I saw the following in the log:
   `java.lang.IllegalStateException`: cannot send more responses than requests
3. On the client side, I got the following error:
   `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException`: The target server failed to respond

What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: Which version ? exceptionCaught(..) should only be called once. We fixed this a while ago, so maybe you should upgrade.

Comment: I am using 3.6.6.Final, which version is the fix in?